# How to uninstall ubuntu 14.04lts?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I am an absolute beginner of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my PC.  How can I remove it ? I want to reinstall it to a clean slate.

Please provide instructions as simply as possible - assume nothing.

Comment: If you want to reinstall, there's no need to remove the system. The installer itself will give you the option to clean (format) all the hardrives during the installation process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Just insert Live-CD or Live-Usb and install new one. When the install manager asks you what to do choose Replace  option.It will automatically remove your current system and install a new one.

You can also choose Do something else option to manage partitions.